# Is this a correct usage of a semicolon: It's not that I don't care; it's that I care too much?

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons, colons

I could see case here for a colon: It's not that I don't care: it's that I care too much.

Or even a comma: It's not that I don't care, it's that I care too much.

Comment: You could use a semicolon, a colon, or, because the clauses are short, even a comma.  In fact, I'd prefer the comma. You could even use a period, for that matter. Ranking them in order of preference, I'd use 1. comma, 2. period, 3. semicolon, 4. colon.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's incorrect as such, but if this is dialogue or a quote I'd be tempted to use a full stop.

> E.g: Hannah turned to Sam with a tear in her eye. "It's not that I
>   don't care. It's that I care too much."

It gives the second half of the statement more emphasis and a longer pause than a semicolon or comma.